# EXCEL VBA: Ignore word document errors and read content

Tags: vba, error-handling, document

> I am writing VBA code to read the word document content and paste them
>   in excel sheets, everything is fine,
>
> but while reading multiple word documents Some of the word document
>   shows the error messages for example "Word could not fire an event",
>   due to this the program hangs up.
>
> Can anyone suggest a VBA code to ignore these type of error and read
>   the word content.
>
> I have my placed code below.

```
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set oDoc = GetObject("D:\176013(1).doc")
str = oDoc.Content.text 
MsgBox (str)
oDoc.Close (0)
```

> Based on the answers

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = **** 'unable to give false here, it shows only three options wdAlertsNone, wdAlertsMessageBox, wdAlertsAll
Set oDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("D:\176013(1).doc")
str = oDoc.Content.text
oDoc.Close (0)
wdApp.Quit False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

If you use other application objects, you have to set `DisplayAlerts = False` on that object.

```
Dim app As Word.Application
Set app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
app.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
On Error Resume Next
Set oDoc = app.Documents.Open("D:\176013(1).doc")
On Error GoTo 0
str = oDoc.Content.text 
MsgBox (str)
oDoc.Close (0)
app.Quit
```

Note: The `On Error Resume Next` statement is risky. It expects you to know the skipped error. If the error corrupts the document, you may not be able to read the contents of this document (in the next line), but the statement `On Error GoTo 0` resets the error handling to default, so if you get an error in that line, the error will be shown.

Comment: This is the code i am using can suggest to place the displayalerts 

Set oDoc = GetObject("D:\176013(1).doc")
str = oDoc.Content.text
MsgBox (str)
oDoc.Close (0)

Comment: If you just open a document with that object, `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` should suffice. Place it in the beginning of your Sub.

Comment: @dasanb Well, that's quite an unclean approach to open a document. Why don't you use an application object? I edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have used as used as u suggested but 'DisplayAlerts' show only three options "wdAlertsNone, wdAlertsMessageBox, wdAlertsAll" it is not accepting false. and now it throws the error "application defined or object defined error". i used wdAlertsNone

Comment: Which line is highlighted with this error? The "DisplayAlerts" one?

Comment: Set oDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("D:\176013(1).doc") on this line it shows the runtime error 6002: application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Well, you can always catch errors and continue with execution of code. I edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Does it work now? If so, feel free to mark this as answer :)

Comment: Though i cant read the document because of this error, now i can ignore the error documents and mark them

Comment: Alright. Maybe you should try to investigate on that original error (word could not fire an event). Glad it helped anyways!